# How to hide the "Set Encoding..." menu in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Do you have any idea how to hide the `Set Encoding` menu in the `Edit Menu`? I had spend some hard time looking for a way to hide this menu.

I try to dig the `plugin.xml` in many plugins with no luck to look for this `Set Encoding` action command.

I can't get the action definition id from plug-in spy that I can use to hide this menu in my developed plugin. I only get the info below:

The active contribution item class:

```
org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.RetargetTextEditorAction
```

The contributing plug-in:

```
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor (3.5.1.r352_v20100105)
```

Comment: Looks like `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditorActionContributor` adds this programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.changeEncoding` action is usually added to the `Edit` menu dynamically by the [IEditorActionBarContributor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IEditorActionBarContributor.html) specified for the `contriubutorClass` attribute of the declared  [org.eclipse.ui.editors](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors.html) extension point.

E.g. the `org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor` gets declared by the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` plugin itself, and specifies the class [TextEditorActionContributor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/editors/text/TextEditorActionContributor.html) as the `contriubutorClass`. `TextEditorActionContributor` does add the `ChangeEncoding` action like so:

```
public void init(IActionBars bars) {
    super.init(bars);

    IMenuManager menuManager= bars.getMenuManager();
    IMenuManager editMenu= menuManager.findMenuUsingPath(IWorkbenchActionConstants.M_EDIT);
    if (editMenu != null)
        editMenu.add(fChangeEncodingAction);
}}
```

So to completely remove this action from the `Edit` menu, you would need to define your own editors by extending [org.eclipse.ui.editors](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors.html) and providing you own implementation of `IEditorActionBarContributor`.

Comment: Hi Balder, thanks for your answer. I think I have no choice but to customise the editor then.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit the perspective, right click on the toolbar in Eclipse and you should get a context menu with the alternative `Customize perspective...`. Then go to the tab `Menu visibility` and disable the menu item you want to hide.